# nav walker menu mobile, the toggle button works but the sub menu quickly disappears

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using nav walker menu in my wordpress theme, it works perfectly fine but there's a small issue on mobile, upon clicking the toggle button the sub menu item disapears after a few seconds.

Here's my Jquery, any help will be highly appreciated!

```
<script>
(function($) {
jQuery(function($) {
$('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {   

  location.href = this.href;
   });
   });
   })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

Comment: Why have u added jquery to it ?

Comment: Hi Manish, yes I've added jQuery, by default in NavWalker menu the parent item is not clickable but I changed that with jQuery and now the parent menu item is linked so on the small screen when you click on the parent item it drops down the sub menu item but then links it to the parent menu link.. I want the toggle function to be added on the small caret not on the parent menu item?

Comment: because I want the parent item to be linked that's why I added Jquery to it.

Comment: all u want is a navbar ??